# jQuery .before() doesn't insert content as I defined it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have following HTML

### Html

```
<aside>
  <section class="links"></section>
  <section class="downloads"></section>
  <section class="news"></section>
  <section class="contact"></section>
<aside>
```

I'm trying to insert `</aside><aside>`before section.news (effectively splitting the aside container tag in 2 aside containers with 2 sections in each)

### jQuery

I use:

```
$("aside section.news").before("</aside><aside>");
```

### Problem

Jquery always prints `<aside></aside>` instead of `</aside><aside>` like I want.

Comment: That's not how DOM functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the "proper" way of doing it:

- Create an aside element
- Insert it after the existing aside element
- Move desired elements inside it

```javascript
var $aside1 = $("aside:first");
var $aside2 = $("<aside><\/aside>").insertAfter($aside1);
$(".news").nextAll().addBack().appendTo($aside2);
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/nzTKs/)

Answer (score 3):

DOM elements are not strings, you can't add elements in that way using JavaScript, DOM elements are JavaScript objects, jQuery behind the scenes calls `createElement()` method of the `document` object  which creates a DOM [HTMLElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#htmlelement) object, it doesn't add strings to the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('</aside><aside>').insertBefore('.news');
```

As

```
<aside>
  <section class="links"></section>
  <section class="downloads"></section>
  </aside><aside>
  <section class="news"></section>
  <section class="contact"></section>
<aside>
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) about .insertBefore

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var one = $('aside').children().eq(0).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html() + $('aside').children().eq(1).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html()
    var two = $('aside').children().eq(2).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html() + $('aside').children().eq(3).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html()
    $('aside').before('<aside>'+one+'</aside');
    $('aside').eq(1).html(two);

    console.log(one)
    console.log(two)
});
```